# Why divergence should be a scalar

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

This question may sound silly but it is fundamental to me.

Divergence is defined as scalar sum of rate of changes of three components of the vector with respect to the axis. I have difficulty to understand why the 3 components should be added together as scalars (why dot product is used to define divergence)? How to understand this quantity represents net flow out/into that point.

Why divergence is not defined as a vector $$ \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}k$$

Comment: We can define things however we want, but why do you think "net flow out/into a point" should be a vector? What would the direction represent? Have you seen any applications of divergence?

Comment: Flow out/into can be vector just like velocity field of liquid flow. Divergence as it is defined is used in first equation of Maxwell's equations. Why shouldn't it be defined as vector?

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661771/proof-that-divergence-of-vector-field-is-a-scalar) is relevant.  The point being that the divergence, as customarily defined, is invariant under coordinate transformations and thus scalar in nature.

Comment: "Divergence is defined as scalar sum of rate of changes of three components of the vector with respect to the axis" That is not the definition I'd use.  Instead, divergence is the trace of covariant derivative, or something similar.

Comment: I think you’re working through the distinction between divergence and flux density.

Comment: @lulu that is really a cool property of divergence defined this way.

Comment: @techie11  Isn't it?   That's the point of looking at the scalar quantity.  Nothing stops you from looking at the vector quantity as well, of course.

Comment: @Aruralreader flux is a scalar its density will also be a scalar

Comment: You might have a look heat  and charge flux density vectors.